# Linear Programm with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Is there a name for problems like this
min norm(Cx)
Ax = b

where C is a matrix and norm is the maximum norm.
This is kind of like a linear Programm. Could this be rewritten as linear programm? Or Any idea how you could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a convex program. For all you ever wanted to know, read [Boyd and Vanderberghe's convex optimization.](https://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) (pdf available for free on same site).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be cast as a Linear Program. Just add an extra variable $z\in \mathbb{R}$ and constraints
$$ z\geq c_i^Tx ,\quad z\geq -c_i^Tx,\quad i=1,\ldots,m$$
where $c_i^T$ is the $i$-th row of $C$.

Although your problem is an LP, be careful since your problem has unbounded domain. Try to write your problem in standard form, so you can use standard methods (simplex, interior-point) for solving it.